# q - cannot load log4q

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I would like to use [log4q](https://github.com/prodrive11/log4q/blob/master/log4q.q). I downloaded the `log4q.q` file to my `%QHOME%` directory. When I try to load the script

```
C:\Dev\q\w32\q.exe -p 5000
q) \l log4q.q
```

I get

```
'
  [0]  (<load>)

  )
```

When I try the same in qpad after connecting to localhost server I get

```
'.log4.q 
(attempt to use variable .log4.q without defining/assigning first (or user-defined signal))
```

which I find strange because I can switch to non-existing namespaces in the console without any issues.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a typo in the first line stemming from a recent change of namespace from .l to .log4q

I think the first line should be:

```
\d .log4q
```

not

```
\d .log4.q
```

Comment: unfortunately that didnt do the trick for me. I still get the same error

Comment: What error did qpad return when you updated that line in the file?